# How to scroll to a particular position in a Listview inside Adapter class?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to scroll to a particular position in listview, but I have to do it inside the adapter class. I use `getItem()` method to find out which item I have to scroll to, which is as follows.

```
public class PropertyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

......

@Override
    public Object getItem( int position ) {
        if ( mPositionType[ position ] == DisplayType.Properties ) {

            return getPropertyForPosition( position - mSectionPositionAdjustment[ DisplayType.Properties.ordinal() ] );
        }

        return mPositionType[ position ];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId( int position ) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        return getDisplayView( position, convertView, parent );
    }

......
```

Now how do I scroll to that position inside this class itself?

Comment: You can create a variable in your adapter class for referencing your listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the list to scroll to a specific position:

```
myListView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
```

if you want to get the position of a specific item in listView:

```
myListView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

also this `listView.getVerticalScrollbarPosition(i)`;

}

if you want to set in the adapter then try to get `ListView` reference in adapter class below is the code for finding the `ListView` inside adapter class. have a look

```
  // See this method of your adapter
 // The parent is the view you are looking for
    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, 
     View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ListView view = (ListView)parent;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is I can't get myListView instance inside adapter class. I have to do it inside adapter class somehow.

Comment: @AadhilAhmed just tell me on which condition you want to scroll.